# R - filter table to return a row which contains only ALL search terms across ALL columns

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, tidyverse, shinyapps

I have the following data

| Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | Blogs |
| Daniel | James |
| Daniel | Joe |

```
data <- filter %>% filter_all(any_vars(grepl(pattern="Joe|Blogs",.) ) )
```

returns two rows, **Joe Blogs and Daniel Joe**

How do I filter so i only get 'Joe Blogs' back.

Basically my actual table has many columns, and i want to have an input search field. The words in the input field should be used to filter the table, and only return rows from the table which have ALL the words in the input field.

Answer (score 3):

For your example using `all_vars` will work.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter_all(all_vars(grepl('Joe|Blogs', .)))

#  Name Surname
#1  Joe   Blogs
```

Since `filter_all` has been superseded you can use `across` as :

```
data %>% filter(across(.fns = ~grepl('Joe|Blogs', .)))
```

However, both of these answer do not guarantee that both `'Joe'` and `'Blogs'` exist in the row. This will also select rows that has `'Joe'` and `'Joe'`  in them. (If that will never happen in your data you can use the answer above).

To make sure that both of the words exist in the row you can use `grepl` separately and check if there is at-least one occurrence of both the words in the row.

```
data %>% filter(rowSums(across(.fns = ~grepl('Joe', .))) > 0 &  
                rowSums(across(.fns = ~grepl('Blogs', .))) > 0)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. when i change any_vars to all_vars, i get 0 rows returned. I've also trying with just 'Joe' only.

Comment: Do you have other columns in your data which you have not shown? Did you try the `rowSums` answer ?